# UnsupportedClassVersionError How to update compiler in eclipse?

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, maven, java-20

I have a project in spring boot (maven) that tries to start, but gives me a version error

Console:

`Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.demoJwt.DemoJwtApplication   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/demoJwt/DemoJwtApplication (class file version 59.65535) was compiled with preview features that are unsupported. This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes preview features for class file version 64.65535`

[Java Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Bil.png)

[Java Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkIx4.png) (I can't find anything more current than version 15)

I want to update the Java Compiler version to version 20 to avoid the error when starting the maven project.

Comment: Why not update the entire Eclipse?

Comment: You need to use the latest Eclipse 2023-06 to get support for the Java 20 compliance level.